# Fetch more than 10000 result from elasticsearch with node.js using search_after

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, pagination

I'm trying to **fetch** more than **10,000 records** from **elasticsearch**, using '**search_after**'. In the official documentation it's was implemented outside the body, but that gave me error. So i did some search and found out that, it should be used under body. I've tried to implement it but, i'm only getting 10,000 results. Also i'm not able to find the pit id in my response. Can anyone help me with this..??

> ###### I'm posting my code below:

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: elasticUrl,
});


const getElasticData = async() => {
    const response = await client.search({
        index: index,
        type: '_doc',
        // size: 10000,
        body: {
          query: {
            match_all: {},
          },
          query: {
            match_all: {},
          },
          sort: [
            {
              "_id": {
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          ],        
          search_after: [10000]
        }
    })
      return response
}

let completeElasticData;

getElasticData().then(res => {
    completeElasticData = res

    let displayMsg = completeElasticData ? `Data fetched from elastic: [ ${completeElasticData.hits.total.value} ]` : `something went wrong`
    
    console.log(displayMsg)

    app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
        res.send(completeElasticData)
    })

}).catch(err => console.log(err));

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Server started on port 5000'));
```

> ###### Below is the view to package.json

```
{
  "name": "elasticdata",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "elasticsearch": "^16.7.2",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have never seen a use case where a search should return more than 10k results. What is your use case here? You certainly don't want to return more than 10k results to an end user. Is there no way for you to narrow down your search to make it return fewer results?

Comment: @dybzon We need to copy all the data to a new server. And moving 10k at a time will take a lot of time, As we have really large number of records present there. That's why i'm trying to make it a bit quick by removing the limitation of 10k results at a time.

Comment: Have you tried [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html)? It can work with remote clusters and it uses the efficient [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/scroll-api.html).